# build caml query for multiple AND & OR

Tags: caml

how to build caml query for following condition. All the fields all from single list.

```
select empid, ename, salary from emp where empid=(100 or 107 or 99 or 103 or 105) and deptno=10 and mgrId=23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='empid'/>
        <FieldRef Name='ename'/>
        <FieldRef Name='salary'/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <In>
                    <FieldRef Name='empid' />
                    <Values>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>100</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>107</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>99</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>103</Value>
                        <Value Type='Integer'>105</Value>
                    </Values>
                 </In>
                <And>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='deptno'/><Value Type='Integer'>10</Value></Eq>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='mgrId'/><Value Type='Integer'>23</Value></Eq>
                </And>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Also you can see list of [caml query builder tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647340.aspx) . You can use any of these tools to further build more queries and test it.